# Do commits of a merged branch become part of master branch after merge?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-commit

Let say I have a `A->B->C` (`master`) branch and `A->B->D->E->F` (`develop`) branch.

After I merge `develop` into `master` a new merge commit is created, say `G`, so master now looks like `A->B->C->G` (master). `G` being a merge commit has two parents, `C` (master) and `F` (develop).

Are all interim commits on develop, i.e. `D->E->F`, now part of `master` after the merge operation?

I think they are since `D` or `E` or `F` can be reached from the merged commit `G` which surely is part of `master`, however I'm not sure. Could somebody confirm or clarify this?

Answer (score 3):

> I'd like to know whether all interim commits on develop i.e. `D->E->F` are now conceptually part of `master` after the merge operation??
>
> IMHO, yes since `D` or `E` or `F` can be reached from the merged commit `G` which surely is part of `master`

That's exactly correct.

You can verify this by [asking Git to list the branches that contain a given commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch---containsltcommitgt), e.g.

```
git branch --contains D
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is one way Git is intended to be used.

Note that you can, if desired, effectively *replace* the three commits on `develop` with a single combined commit (a different commit).  You can make that combined commit only on `master`, then discard branch `develop` entirely so that no one uses the original three commits.  The `git merge --squash` command lets you achieve this in two steps: do the squash-merge (which is not a true merge), then delete the `develop` branch.  Note that anyone else trying to use `develop` will have to accommodate this: they may have to delete their own `develop` branch too.

Or, you can `git reset` away the three commits on `develop`, in favor of a new combined commit you make and place at the rewound tip of `develop`.  You can then merge this normally, if you like.  The `git rebase -i` (interactive rebase) command is useful for this particular workflow.  Note that once again, anyone else trying to use `develop` will have to accommodate this: if they have built commits upon the original three commits that you're replacing with a combined single commit, they will need to do their own rebasing.

There are many other options.  Each have various advantages and disadvantages; Git lets you do whichever you like best.  But the one you outline in your question is the one Git makes the simplest and easiest, and it's often a good choice.